# Is necesary to add empty signature appearance on a PDF to be signed by multiple users

Tags: pdf, digital-signature

Let's say we have generated a PDF to be signed by two users. The signing process will handled on server side, so the PDF file will be updated (digital signature & timestamp) on server side. No external applications (like adobe reader or pro) will be involved on this process.

Do I need to create two "empty signature appearance" on this PDF file?

Comment: First of all, you certainly don't need specific signature *appearances*.  Furthermore, empty signature *fields* can be helpful to lock field after signing but aren't strictly necessary either.